# MVAPICH2 RDMA-based communication without explicit PUT/GET use?

Tags: mpi, hpc, infiniband, rdma, mvapich2

My cluster utilizes MVAPICH2 over Infiniband FDR and and I am considering the 
 use of RDMA for my simulations. I am aware of the MPI_Put and MPI_Get calls for explicitly invoking RDMA operations, however I would like to know if this is the only way to use RDMA within MPI.

My current implementation involves channel semantics (send/receive) for communication, along with `MPI_Reduce` and `MPI_Gatherv`. I know that MVAPICH2 has configuration paramaters that can be used to enable RDMA. If a program using MPI has send/receive calls and RDMA is enabled, does MPI automatically convert from channel semantics over to memory semantics (put/get) or is the explicit use of `MPI_Put` and `MPI_Get` the only method for implementing RDMA in MVAPICH2?

`MPI_Send` requires a corresponding `MPI_Receive`, whether they are blocking or non-blocking doesnt matter as a send must be met with a receive. RDMA does not have this requirement and instead only implements either `MPI_Put` (write to remote memory) or `MPI_Get` (read from remote memory). I am trying to find out if enabling rdma while still using send and receives, allows MVAPICH2 to somehow automatically convert the send/receives into the appropriate rdma call.

Comment: Welcome, can you add an example?

Comment: There really is no "example" of this this. Either MVAPICH2 will use RDMA or it wont for the utilized constructs, and that is the question.

Comment: An example makes easier to test.

Comment: There is nothing to "test" here. Either MVAPICH2 will use RDMA in place of send/receive when RDMA is enabled or it wont unless put/get is explicitly used.

Comment: I am not an expert in MPI, but there is no reason to think that RDMA is different from `MPI_Send` and `MPI_Receive`, which may well be how `MPI_Put` and `MPI_Get` are implemented and run (in a dedicated thread) behind the scenes. Maybe Put/Get can exploit some special hardware in a special system, but that's it. I don't know mvapich but openmpi has the command `ompi_info --all` from which you can extract a lot of information on how the system is configured.

Comment: This was a very good question since OpenSHMEM is the only thing that explicitly does gather operations using RDMA.  Thanks for asking it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If MVAPICH2 has been built with the correct options, it will use RDMA for all MPI operations including `MPI_Send` and `MPI_Recv` on supported hardware, which includes InfiniBand. So, you do not need to use `MPI_Put/Get` to take advantage of RDMA-capable hardware. In fact, using `MPI_Send/Recv` might be faster because they are often better optimized.

MPI libraries use various designs to translate `MPI_Send/Recv` operations to RDMA semantics. [The details can be found in the literature](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1023/B:IJPP.0000029272.69895.c1.pdf).